# Android studio terminal not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, adb

After I have tried to change the `ADB shell` location from `cmd.exe` to the `.../sdk/platform-tools` in order to run `ADB` commands from `Android Studio`, the terminal is popping up and immediately closing back when I try to open it.

**P.S.** I have the latest version of `Android Studio` at the time of posting this question.

Comment: Please show any errors you can (trace/stack). **Obviously** change it *back* **for now** while we investigate. Seems like you broke it ;O). More detail required. No elipses (...) we want the actual stuff.

Comment: Seems like I just had to edit the path environment variable and change the shell path back to cmd.exe, now tell me how can I upvote your comment, Thank you :).

Comment: `"now tell me how can I upvote your comment, Thank you :)"`
I have put it in a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948453/android-studio-terminal-not-showing/58045099#58045099)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I have tried to change the `ADB shell` location from `cmd.exe` to
>   the .../sdk/platform-tools in order to run ADB commands from `Android`
>   Studio, the terminal is popping up and immediately closing back when I
>   try to open it.

See [What are `PATH` and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Here we go... If you are *changing/adding/deleting* to your system [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable...be **careful** and **back it up first** (it's text, it's a relatively small string of paths, exact method/syntax/delimiter *varies* with OS {windows/unix/linux/Mac...}). It's the way a terminal or other programs can easily find the *unique* executable (via system a variable called [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))).

**NOTE**: the PATH can get cluttered over time, keep it clean !

## Windows example (**delimiter** "**;**"):

```
Path=C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\gtkmm\bin;C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7
.0\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\PROGRAM FILES\ATI TECHNOLOGIE
S\ATI CONTROL PANEL;C:\PROGRAM FILES\SUPPORT TOOLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\WINDOWS
\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Micr
osoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\SFU\common\;C:\Program Files\OpenSG 2.0.0\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4\bin;C
:\Program Files\Bakefile;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR;C:\wxWidgets-2.9.4\samples\adt-bundl
e-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\wxWidgets-2.9.4\samples\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\android-ndk-r9d;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\
Core-Static;C:\Bullet\fbx-conv\fbx-conv-master\build\vs2008\bin\Release;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\java\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\Program Files\And
roid\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Fil
es\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\scala\bin;C:\squid\sbin;C:\Documents and Settings\john\Application Data\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin;C
:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

## UNIX/LINUX/Android example (**delimiter** "**:**"):

```
PATH=.:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/guile/2.0:C:/cygwin/usr/local/lib/guile/2.0:/c/wxWidgets-2.9.3:/c/Documents and Settings/john/GNUstep/Tools:/mingw/bin:/c/Progr
am Files/Embarcadero/RAD Studio/7.0/bin:/c/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/RAD Studio/7.0/Bpl:/c/Perl/bin/:/c/watcom/BINNT:/c/watcom/BINW:/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32:/c/WINDOWS:
/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/WBEM:/c/PROGRAM FILES/SUPPORT TOOLS/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/Common7/IDE:/c/Python26:/GNUstep/System/Tools:/mingw/bin:/GNUstep/Local/Tools:.:
/lib:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/cygdrive/c/Dev-Cpp/bin:/mingw/bin:/cygdrive/c/watcom/binw:/cygdrive/c/watcom/binnt:/cygdrive/c/Python26:/cygdrive/c/Python24:/cygdrive/c/perl/bin:'/cygdri
ve/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/bin':/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/Oracl
e/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/gtkmm/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Embarcadero/RAD Studio/7.0/bin:/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/RAD Studio/7.0/Bpl:/cygdrive/c
/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/WBEM:/cygdrive/c/PROGRAM FILES/ATI TECHNOLOGIES/ATI CONTROL PANEL:/cygdrive/c/PROGRAM FILES/SUPPORT TOOLS:/cygdri
ve/c/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/doxygen/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Perforce:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/
c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShel
l/Common7/IDE:/cygdrive/c/SFU/common:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/OpenSG 2.0.0/bin:/usr/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Bakefile:/cygdrive/c/Progr
am Files/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR:/cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-2.9.4/samples/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702/sdk/
platform-tools:/cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-2.9.4/samples/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030/android-ndk-r9d:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/cygdrive/c/Bullet
/fbx-conv/fbx-conv-master/build/vs2008/bin/Release:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/cygdrive/c/java/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Android/Android S
tudio/gradle/gradle-2.4/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/c/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin:/cygdrive/c/
Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/scala/bin:/cygdrive/c/squid/sbin:/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/john/Application Data/npm/
node_modules/cordova/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs
```

**And so on...**

Answer (score 1):

To show terminal, go to the superior option "View", then go to the option "Tool Windows" and then go to "Terminal". You also can use Alt + F12 command.